# Accessing Digital Signature Token on android mobile

Tags: android, digital-signature, drivers, usb-otg

I am trying to develop an android app which has a functionality to digitally sign the document. I am using OTG cable to connect the Digital Signature Token (say Moserbaer token) with mobile phone. But android is not recognizing the Token (It is recognizing the Pendrive if i plug), Of course it will be needing the Moserbaer token drivers.

Question is how to install the drivers and how to access the digital signature in my app programmatically from the token itself.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers for cryptographic hardware on many systems come in the form of the shared library (DLL on Windows, Shared Object .so file on Unix-based systems) which implements PKCS#11 API and offers it to the application. The application loads the shared library and calls PKCS#11 functions from it.

If the developer provides PKCS#11 drivers for Android, then you can use the device via PKCS#11 interface. If such library is not provided, then most likely you are out of luck.